# how can I put the files at the root of my repository into a new directory?

Tags: git, github, repository

I have looked around for previous questions like this, and most of them deal with moving the root directory into another directory in the repository.
I would like to do the opposite, and it becomes confusing determining which way some askers want to go. so here I am with my own question.
I have a project layout that looks something like this.

```
-Project
- -Example1 
- -Example2
- -Project[repository]
- - -projfile.h
- - -projfile.cpp
- - -main.cpp
- - -project.vcxproj
- - -project.git
    ...
- -project.sln
  ...
...
```

I did git init in the nested project folder.

can I move the root of the git commit one folder back to clean things up a bit, without having to start a new project?
 I've already pushed a couple of commits and I don't want to lose that progress.

at the very least is there some way I clean up the project by putting all the files into a new directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can move the entire contents along with `.git folder` to the root folder, without changing anything. Except that folders Example 1 and anything in root folder will also be available for commit, you could add them to `.gitignore` if you don't want to stage and commit them.

`.git` hidden folder contains all information on commits. If the contents of your repository stays same relative to that folder.. you can move them wherever you want.

It would look like this:

```
-Project
- -Example1 
- -Example2
- -projfile.h
- -projfile.cpp
- -main.cpp
- -project.vcxproj
- -project.git << **.git**
    ...
- -project.sln
```

Comment: If I do as you say, and move the entire contents of the .git folder one directory up, to the intended root folder, will I then be able to add them back to their own directory? minus whatever it is that makes that folder the repository?
my main issue is that when you open the project on git hub, all the source files are just right there, and yes, I will eventually want to add the example, but would exclude them at the moment.

Comment: Move the . git folder as is, not cut paste its contents. Wherever .git folder exists is considered the repository

Comment: Git would assume nothing changed, except for the new files. PS : I've edited my answer. I hope its clear

Answer (score 0):

Move the `.git` folder up and commit the changes, as git will think you moved everything around.